# App Crashing while Reopening Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

Hello Everyone My app is getting crashed when the tabs are opened randomly and it is giving error like this in my logcat can any one help me in fixing this

In this fragment I integrated Displaying map information in Listview header for that I'm using SupportMapFragment

Here Is my following code

```
public class ChainTab extends Fragment implements ResponseListner, OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    String TAG = ChainTab.class.getSimpleName();

    String bottleId;
    String url;

    ListView bottleChainListView;
//    NonScrollListView bottleChainListView;

    Context context;

    View rootView;

    String responseVal;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private String provider = null;
    private Marker mCurrentPosition = null;
    ProgressDialog PD;
    private List<BottleInfoModel> bottleInfoModelList;
    private List<CreatedAt> createdAtList;
    private List<UpdatedAt> updatedAtList;
    private List<Scans> scansList;
    private Polyline mPolyline = null;
    private LatLng mSourceLatLng = null;
    private LatLng mDestinationLatLng = null;

    TextView serialNoTV, entityNameTV, productTypeChainTV, originTV, getQTYUOM, entityType;



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chain_tab, viewGroup, false);

        bottleInfoModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        createdAtList = new ArrayList<CreatedAt>();
        updatedAtList = new ArrayList<>();
        scansList = new ArrayList<>();
        context = getActivity();


        bottleChainListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottleChainListView);

        return rootView;
    }



    public void displayMsgs(NdefMessage[] msgs) {



        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0)
            return;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        List<ParsedNdefRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);
        final int size = records.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ParsedNdefRecord record = records.get(i);
            String str = record.str();
            builder.append(str).append("\n");
        }


        Log.i(TAG,"NFC Id Value is :: "+builder.toString().trim());
//        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//        bottleSerialNo = textVal.getText().toString().trim();
//        bottleSerialNo = "testing";

        ServerHit serverHit = new ServerHit();

//        url = AppConfig.REGISTER_BOTTLE_INFO + "/" + builder.toString().trim();
        url = AppConfig.REGISTER_BOTTLE_INFO + "/" + "testing";

        if(context != null)
            serverHit.getScannedBottleInfo(context, url, this);
        else
            Log.i(TAG, "Context Value is  Null....154");
    }

    @Override
    public String onResponse(String response) {



        responseVal = response;

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

            JSONObject payloadObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("payload");

//            for (int i =0; i<payloadObject.length(); i++){


            JSONArray jsonArray = payloadObject.getJSONArray("scans");
            BottleInfoModel bottleInfoModel = new BottleInfoModel();


            bottleInfoModel.setEntityName(payloadObject.getString("entityName"));
            bottleInfoModel.setEntityType(payloadObject.getString("entityType"));


            JSONObject createdDateObj = payloadObject.getJSONObject("created_at");
            CreatedAt createdAt = new CreatedAt();
            createdAt.setDate(createdDateObj.getString("date"));
            createdAtList.add(createdAt);
            bottleInfoModel.setCreatedAtList(createdAtList);

            for (int j = 0; j <= jsonArray.length() - 1; j++) {

                JSONObject jsonObjectScan = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                Scans scansModel = new Scans();
                scansModel.setEntityType(jsonObjectScan.getString("entityType"));
                scansModel.setEntityName(jsonObjectScan.getString("entityName"));
                scansModel.setCreated_at(jsonObjectScan.getString("created_at"));
                scansModel.setLat(jsonObjectScan.getString("lat"));
                scansModel.setLongVal(jsonObjectScan.getString("long"));
                scansList.add(scansModel);
            }
            bottleInfoModel.setScansList(scansList);

            bottleInfoModelList.add(bottleInfoModel);

//            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
//            View viewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chaintab_lv_header, bottleChainListView, false);



            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chaintab_lv_header,bottleChainListView, false);
//            viewLand=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_land,null);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_track_order_map_fragment);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            entityNameTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.entityNameTV);
            serialNoTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.serialNoTV);
            entityType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.entityType);
            getQTYUOM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.getQTYUOM);
            originTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.originTV);
            productTypeChainTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productTypeChainTV);

            entityNameTV.setText(payloadObject.getString("entityName"));
            serialNoTV.setText("#" + payloadObject.getString("serialNumber"));
            entityType.setText(payloadObject.getString("entityType"));
            getQTYUOM.setText(payloadObject.getString("qtyUOM"));

            productTypeChainTV.setText(payloadObject.getString("productDescription"));


            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");

            String mainChapterNumber = createdDateObj.getString("date").split("\\.", 2)[0];
            Log.i("Value iss....", "Value is :: " + mainChapterNumber);

            Date date = null;

            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                date = format.parse(mainChapterNumber);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            String originStr = null, dateStr = null;
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(payloadObject.getString("origin") + " " + formatter.format(date));
            if (matcher.find()) {
                originStr = payloadObject.getString("origin");
                dateStr = formatter.format(date).toString().trim();
            }

            originStr = setMultiColor(originStr, "#363636");
            dateStr = setMultiColor(dateStr, "#87CEFA");


            originTV.setText(Html.fromHtml(originStr + " " + dateStr));
            ChainItemsAdapter chainItemsAdapter = new ChainItemsAdapter(context, scansList);


//            ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.chaintab_lv_header,bottleChainListView,false);


            bottleChainListView.addHeaderView(view);

            bottleChainListView.setAdapter(chainItemsAdapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // This block is used while implementing the things with chain api url link
/*
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

            JSONArray payloadJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("payload");

            for (int i=0; i<payloadJsonArray.length(); i++){

                BottleInfoModel bottleInfoModel = new BottleInfoModel();

                JSONObject payloadJOBJ = payloadJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                bottleInfoModel.setLongVal(payloadJOBJ.getString("long"));
                bottleInfoModel.setLatVal(payloadJOBJ.getString("lat"));
                bottleInfoModel.setEntityName(payloadJOBJ.getString("entityName"));
                bottleInfoModel.setSerialNumber(payloadJOBJ.getString("bottleId"));

                CreatedAt createdAt = new CreatedAt();
                JSONObject jsonObjectCreatedAt = payloadJOBJ.getJSONObject("created_at");


                    createdAt.setDate(jsonObjectCreatedAt.getString("date"));
                    createdAt.setTimezone(jsonObjectCreatedAt.getString("timezone"));
                    createdAt.setTimezone_type(jsonObjectCreatedAt.getString("timezone_type"));

                    createdAtList.add(createdAt);


                bottleInfoModel.setCreatedAtList(createdAtList);

                bottleInfoModelList.add(bottleInfoModel);
            }

            entityNameTV.setText(bottleInfoModelList.get(0).getEntityName());
            serialNoTV.setText(bottleInfoModelList.get(0).getSerialNumber());

            ChainItemsAdapter chainItemsAdapter = new ChainItemsAdapter(context, bottleInfoModelList);
            bottleChainListView.setAdapter(chainItemsAdapter);;

        }catch (JSONException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        return null;
    }

    private String setMultiColor(String text, String color) {
        String input = "<font color=" + color + ">" + text + "</font>";
        return input;
    }

    @Override
    public JSONObject onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                break;
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
//        LatLng target = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        addMarks(mMap);

        if (isProviderAvailable() && (provider != null)) {
            locateCurrentPosition();
        }

    }

    private void locateCurrentPosition() {

        int status = context.getPackageManager().checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                context.getPackageName());

        if (status == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
            //  mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
            long minTime = 5000;// ms
            float minDist = 5.0f;// meter
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDist,
                    this);
        }

    }

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        if (location != null && provider != null) {
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            double lat = location.getLatitude();

            mSourceLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

//            addBoundaryToCurrentPosition(lat, lng);

            CameraPosition camPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(lat, lng)).zoom(8).build();

//            mMap.getCameraPosition().target

//            if (mMap != null)
//                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
//                        .newCameraPosition(camPosition));
        } else {
            Log.d("Location error", "Something went wrong");
        }
    }

    private void addBoundaryToCurrentPosition(double lat, double lang) {
        MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        mMarkerOptions.position(new LatLng(lat, lang));
        mMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        mMarkerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);

        CircleOptions mOptions = new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(lat, lang)).radius(10000)
                .strokeColor(0x110000FF).strokeWidth(1).fillColor(0x110000FF);
        mMap.addCircle(mOptions);
        if (mCurrentPosition != null)
            mCurrentPosition.remove();
        mCurrentPosition = mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions);
    }

    private boolean isProviderAvailable() {

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(
                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        if (mLocationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

            return true;
        }

        if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
            return true;
        }

        if (provider != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void addMarks(GoogleMap mMap) {

//        displayResponseVal(responseVal);

        List<LatLng> latLngsList = new ArrayList<>();
        mMap = mMap;

        Polyline polylineOptions = null;
        LatLng latLng = null;
//        for (int i = 0; i < bottleInfoModelList.size(); i++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < scansList.size(); i++) {
            Scans scanInfoModel = scansList.get(i);

            double latval, longVal;

            try {

                latval = Double.parseDouble(scanInfoModel.getLat());
                longVal = Double.parseDouble(scanInfoModel.getLongVal());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                latval = 0;
                longVal = 0;
            }
            latLng = new LatLng(latval, longVal);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(scanInfoModel.getEntityName());
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) this);

            latLngsList.add(latLng);

        }

        drawRouteOnMap(mMap, latLngsList);

    }

    private void drawRouteOnMap(GoogleMap mMap, List<LatLng> latLngsList) {
        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
        options.addAll(latLngsList);
        Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(options);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latLngsList.get(0).latitude, latLngsList.get(0).longitude))
                .zoom(8)
                .build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;
    }
}
```

It corresponding log error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: winepoc.tw.net.winepoc, PID: 17576
java.lang.IllegalStateException: onGetLayoutInflater() cannot be executed until the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager.
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1249)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1201)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1231)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1217)
at winepoc.tw.net.winepoc.fragments.ChainTab.onResponse(ChainTab.java:199)
\at winepoc.tw.net.winepoc.ServerHit$3.onResponse(ServerHit.java:80)
at winepoc.tw.net.winepoc.ServerHit$3.onResponse(ServerHit.java:71)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:78)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: show some code how you are using it

Answer (score 3):

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
if(activity != null){

    // etc ...

}
```

try this i think your activity is null in coding

Comment: Sorry to say Its still repeating. I added SupportMapFragment in my fragment displaying maps in listview header I'm expecting cause of issue is "SupportMapFragment" can you say how can I deal with this